# Swap icon based on data collapsed not working

Tags: css, angular

I have a dropdown list and i wanted to change the chevron-up and chevron-down icons based on if the data is collapsed or not.

I am not sure what is wrong with my current structure that will not allow the icons to swap on collapsing and expanding data.

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-collapse-icon="ChevronDown" data-expand-icon="ChevronUp" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="advancedCollapse" href="#advancedCollapse">
    <span class="win-icon"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code provided, looks like your syntax is incorrect. It should be similar to:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">
  <h1>Collapsed State</h1>
  <p>Expanded state</p>
</div>
```

For more reference, you can check out http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/content/content-collapsible.html

https://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_collapsible_icons